How to highlight some dates in CalendarDatePicker on Avalonia?
I need to highlight some dates in the CalendarDatePicker on Avalonia. This is what I'm doing now, but the Background color of the selected dates only changes when I hover over that date.
What am I doing wrong?
<CalendarDatePicker Name="CalendarDate" SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}" Width="200" >
    <CalendarDatePicker.Styles >
        <Style Selector="CalendarDayButton">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectedDatesMultiConverter}">
                    <Binding x:DataType="CalendarDayButton"/>
                    <Binding Path="$parent[CalendarDatePicker].DataContext.SelectedDates"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </CalendarDatePicker.Styles>
</CalendarDatePicker>

